# How to make stepper motor example interactive

Tags: assembly, rotation, x86-16

I have stepper motor code that visualizes how a stepper motor works, with a rotation degree of 22.5. That works fine
However, I want to make it interactive, i.e if  a button to the right is clicked, the motor rotates that way. Not a full idea, and I am open to suggestions.
Any ideas?

***EDIT***
By button I don't mean a hardwired button, just any form of user input. be it mouse click or keyboard press or whatever.

PS: I'm using emu8086

The code:

```
; this is an example of out instruction.
; it writes values to virtual i/o port
; that controls the stepper-motor.
; c:\emu8086\devices\stepper_motor.exe is on port 7

#start=stepper_motor.exe#


name "stepper"

#make_bin#

steps_before_direction_change = 10h ; 16 (decimal)

jmp start

; ========= data ===============

; bin data for clock-wise
; half-step rotation:
datcw    db 6
         db 4
         db 3
         db 2

; bin data for counter-clock-wise
; half-step rotation:
datccw   db 3
         db 1
         db 6
         db 2


; bin data for clock-wise
; full-step rotation:
datcw_fs db 1
         db 3
         db 6
         db 0

; bin data for counter-clock-wise
; full-step rotation:
datccw_fs db 4
          db 6
          db 3
          db 0


start:
mov bx, offset datcw ; start from clock-wise half-step.
mov si, 0
mov cx, 0 ; step counter

next_step:
; motor sets top bit when it's ready to accept new command
wait:   in al, 7     
        test al, 10000000b
        jz wait

mov al, [bx][si]
out 7, al

inc si

cmp si, 4
jb next_step
mov si, 0

inc cx
cmp cx, steps_before_direction_change
jb  next_step

mov cx, 0
add bx, 4 ; next bin data

cmp bx, offset datccw_fs
jbe next_step

mov bx, offset datcw ; return to clock-wise half-step.

jmp next_step
```

Comment: You mean keyboard input?  Or are you trying to implement a mouse-pointer GUI in your 8086 emulator?  Accepting keyboard or mouse input has nothing to do with what you decide to do with that input (i.e. running OUT instructions), so that would be a more appropriate question title.

Comment: @PeterCordes : EMU8086 has a number of virtual devices that are accessed via ports that do things like stepper motors, produce buttons etc

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, in interactive mode you have still to do the 4x`out` from one of the table.

So maybe something like:

```
direction = ?
step_type = 0/1 ; half / full

input_loop:

input = read buttons  ; wait until some legal input is received
  ; (not sure what you mean by "button", if real HW wire one,
  ; then also debounce properly here)

switch(input) {
  toggle_step_type: step_type ^= 1;
  right: direction = 0
  left: direction = 1
}
table_address = datcw + direction*4 + step_type*8;

... "play" the table from table_address as before,
... but just one cycle (like cx = 1).
... wait for the motor to be ready (current code would, so it's OK)

go back to input_loop
```

Comment: So what I gather from this is get user input, e.g mouse click or keyboard press, and then emulate moving the motor either a full or half step in that direction?
This might be easier with keyboard, because I can make specific action happen with specific ASCII inputs, then get the user to use WASD instead of arrows. Thoughts?